# Assign a variable for nested element

Tags: javascript

How do I assign a variable for the svg inside the div with an ID of `parent1` in javascript?

structure

```
<div id="parent1">
   <svg.....></svg>
</div>
```

js

```
var target = document.getElementById("parent1").svg;
```

Comment: `var target = document.getElementById("parent1").querySelector('svg')`, is this what you want?

Comment: Or even `var target = document.querySelector('#parent1 svg');`.

Comment: @JacobThomas or `var target = document.querySelector('#parent1 > svg')`

Comment: exactly :) Please post your answers I'll upvote both of your answers. cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As shown in the comments, there is a few answers to this.

1. you can query an element for children, grandchildren, etc.

```
var target = document.getElementById("parent1").querySelector('svg')
```

2. grabs first svg under the `#parent` in the heirarchy (melpomene's answer)

```
var target = document.querySelector('#parent1 svg');
```

3. grabs only a direct child svg in `#parent` (j08691's answer)

```
var target = document.querySelector('#parent1 > svg')
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
var target = document.querySelector('#parent1 svg');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to find elements by [CSS selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors).

For an `svg` element inside of an element with id `parent1`, it would be

```
var target = document.querySelector('#parent1 svg');
```